# Php time comparison

Tags: php, mysql, strtotime

I am using the following code to send some alerts to my users. For instance if a user's date of journey is at 04:00:00, he has to receive alerts from 03:00:00 to 06:00:00. That is minus one hour and adding 2 hours. How can i get the records falling in this window.

I tried different combination of time windows but i couldnt make it.

```
$time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$time_1 = strtotime($time) - 3600; // minus 1 hour to current time
$time_2 = strtotime($time) + 7200; // Add 2 hours to current time
$time_to_compare1 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time_1); 
$time_to_compare2 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time_2);
select * FROM  `journey_tracker` where push='0' and batch = '$batch' and doj between      '$time_to_compare1' and '$time_to_compare2'
```

The above code fails because it returns a record with time of journey 05:00:00 or 06:00:00

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM `journey_tracker`
WHERE push='0'
  AND batch = '$batch'
  AND doj BETWEEN DATE_ADD(doj, INTERVAL -1 HOUR) AND DATE_ADD(doj, INTERVAL 2 HOUR)
```

Comment: I would like to get a record with -1hours and plus 2 hours to date of journey. Your code and my code would return would return a record with -3hours also

Comment: Can we do it mysql instead of creating a window in php

Comment: checking now pls wait